# Eclipse Luna scroll cant be dark

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to make my eclipse full dark on windows OS. This is what happened:

[image]

The scroll is still white (on the right), both in "Dark" and "Moonrise" theme. I googled a lot and found out that i must update my eclipse to 4.4.1. I updated my eclipse, but the problem persists.

Please help me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because scrollbars color is set in your desktop environment settings. E.g. windows, or gnome.
To make eclipse using dark scheme you need few steps:

- Install/configure any dark theme for your desktop environment. For linux / Gnome 3 Flashback I suggest using [GnomishDark](http://tsujan.deviantart.com/art/GnomishDark-300548460).
- Install "Eclipse Color Themes" plugin to Eclipse from Marketplace.
- Choose theme you like in Eclipse (General -> Appearance -> Color Theme). E.g. I used Wombat.
- If you want change some other colors, look here:

  General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts

  General -> Editors ->Text Editors -> Annotations

  General -> Editors ->Text Editors -> Quick Diff

  General -> Editors ->Structured Text Editors

You can see my eclipse with GnomishDark theme [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4390886/eclipse.png).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im using windows and already use "Eclipse Color Themes" plugin. Is there any way to change the windows to dark?

Comment: AFAIR you can configure the colors yourself, but you also can use some themes like here http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-dark-windows-themes-skins-reduce-eye-strain/

Comment: Thanks, i used dark agility theme